Spring Boot OpenCsv - NullPointerException when using EntityManager in repository class
I am encountering a NullPointerException when trying to use the EntityManager within the NationalCodeCheck repository class in my Spring Boot application.
Here is the relevant code snippet from the NationalCodeCheck class:
@Repository
public class NationalCodeCheck implements NationalCodeCheckImpl {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    // Method causing NullPointerException
    public boolean checkNationalCode(RightsOffering rightsOffering) throws Exception {
        // EntityManager operations causing NullPointerException
    }
}


and this is my opencsv bean verifier class :
@Component
public class NationalCodeVerifier implements com.opencsv.bean.BeanVerifier<RightsOffering> {

    @Autowired
    private NationalCodeCheck nationalCodeCheck;


    @Override
    public boolean verifyBean(RightsOffering rightsOffering) throws CsvConstraintViolationException {


        boolean isCodeCorrect = false;

        try {
            isCodeCorrect = nationalCodeCheck.checkNationalCode(rightsOffering);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (!isCodeCorrect) {
            throw new CsvConstraintViolationException("Incorrect National Code");

        }
        return true;
    }
}



I have ensured that the @PersistenceContext annotation is used to inject the EntityManager.
I have checked the JPA configuration to confirm that it is set up properly.
I have examined the initialization and usage of the EntityManager within the NationalCodeCheck class.
Despite these efforts, the NullPointerException persists. How can I resolve this issue and successfully use the EntityManager within the NationalCodeCheck repository class?
Any suggestions, insights, or advice on further troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!
